# On finitely additive premeasures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Any interval of the form $(a, b]$ or $(a, \infty)$ is called an $h$-interval, where $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ (see for example, Folland [1] page 33). Let $\mathcal{A}_h$ be the set consisting of all finite unions of $h$-intervals. It is easily checked that $\mathcal{A}_h$ is an algebra.

My question is this:

> Does there exist a finitely additive premeasure $\mu$ on
>   $\mathcal{A}_h$ such that $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$, but that $\mu$ is not
>   countable additive?

For the reference, a finitely additive premeasure $\mu$ on a set $X$ is defined by a map $\mu: \mathcal{A}\to [0, \infty]$ where $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. And that we require $\mu$ to be finitely additive, i.e. $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ whenever $A, B\subseteq X$ are disjoint sets.

My thoughts: The most common premeasure is $\mu = \textrm{length}$ which, by Caratheodory's Theorem extends to concept of Lebesgue measures. But here, we are interested in something pathological; we require that $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$.

Thanks!

[1] *Real analysis - Modern Techniques, and Their Applications* by Gerald B. Folland.

Comment: I would hardly call $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$ pathological... In fact I would call it a probability measure.

Comment: @nullUser: Oh right! It just tells how inexperienced I am with probability measures. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\mu((a,b]) = 0$ for all $a,b$ and $\mu((a,\infty)) = 1$ for all $a$. Clearly we have finite additivity, but we cannot have countable additivitly, else we would have $1 = \mu((0,\infty]) = \sum \mu((n,n+1]) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Excellent example. Once I have 15 reputation points, I will upvote this answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can accept (if you are satisfied) at any reputation.